# parallax slider not working properly from last slide

Tags: javascript, css, html, slider, parallax

I am using a parallax slider on my site, I want to load the last slide as the beginning slide. Is it possible with the code in the below link ?

```
www.codepen.io/fgnass/pen/lwhma
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in this documentation for help.

https://github.com/lyfeyaj/swipe

According to documentation, `startSlide` parameter sets which slide will be the first. You can set this parameter like this:

```
startSlide: 2
```